# How can you create simple iOS application prototypes using Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, prototype

With only a basic knowledge of Objective-C and Xcode 4, is it possible to create prototypes of iPhone apps in Xcode?

For example, can you create a wireframe of an application, where simple touches on the screen trigger actions like navigating down a level in a table view?

Are there any tutorials or guides out there that might explain how to do quick prototyping of iOS applications in Xcode?

Comment: You could buy one of the many apps on the iTunes Appstore and mock-up an app using your iOS device - requires no coding knowledge either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a NavigationController, I followed the tutorial we
found here: 
http://fuelyourcoding.com/iphone-view-switching-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

On the iPad, there's an app called [App Cooker](http://www.appcooker.com/).

It's relatively expensive, and somewhat incomplete, but some time in the next few weeks the app will be finished and it may go up in price. I've downloaded it and I'm impressed by its potential.The missing parts at the moment are some of the UIKit controls in the mockup tool. (Which, again, according to the developers, should be corrected in the near future.) Aside from that, the app is really powerful.  It can do among other things, mockups which you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

The [Briefs framework](http://giveabrief.com/) provides a fast means of making interactive wireframes for iOS applications.  Without writing much code, you can quickly pull together a prototype of your application from images made up to look like your various UI elements.

Also, if the video is still available somewhere, I'd watch Apple's WWDC 2009 session "Prototyping iPhone User Interfaces."  It had some great tips and examples for how you can quickly assemble and test an iPhone interface without writing a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's the simulator which enables you to see the app without requiring you to have a device (or be a registered developer). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yup I know the simulator .. But thats not What I meant .. Am looking for some simple codes that will help me to see the look and feel of the app with out the functionality inside... like dynamic wireframes

Comment: Ah...I use powerpoint for that...make the blocks clickable and navigate to links within the presentation (and disable the click-to-advance setting)

Answer (score 0):

Without actually coding up your views and buttons, there isn't really a way to wireframe your app in XCode. XCode 4 has a new storyboard option that will help you visualize how the views are loaded, but it won't really help you much in the way of running it in the simulator.

Comment: Thank you your response .. I thought there might be some few lines of codes which help only in navigation .. like going to next screen when tapped .  it will look like an finished app in the simulator .. but just the look .. not working functionally.

Comment: No problem. Wiring up a navigation controller isn't too hard if you just want to get it up and running. But unfortunately there isn't anything baked into XCode for creating app mock ups. Business opportunity?

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me for self ads, but we've just released free lib for Axure to prototype iOS apps.
Check it out: http://www.alterplay.com/ios-dev-tips/2012/04/prototyping-ios-applications.html

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use Phototapper?
If your requirement is just tappable app and you are using xCode to build screens alone. Better to go for prototyping apps.
sketch your screens on a paper, capture and link them. This app can also be used to simulate on the web and receive feedback when someone views or comments. They also have option to use highlights on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I use Keynotes on Mac. Create a template the size of your device, add contents and buttons, and off you go!